# Dynamic Select in FormType in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a dynamic select tag in my index.twig The code of the select is

```
 <select name="portfolio" style="width: 265px; height:28px;">
   <option selected="selected" value="default">Switch Your Portfolio</option>
   {% for portfolio in portfolios %}
      <option value={{ portfolio.id }}>{{ portfolio.portfolioName }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Now I have SwitchPortfolioType and I want to create this dynamic select inside my Type

```
class SwitchPortfolioType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
   {
    $builder
    ->add('availability', 'choice', array(
        'choices'   => array(
            //dynamic options here
     ),
            'empty_value' => 'Switch your Portfolio',
    ));
   }
}
```

How can I do this in Symfony2

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented the code in our project in this way.....

```
class SwitchPortfolioType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
   {

       $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('parentid', 'entity', array('class'=>'MusicCoreBundle:MusicCategory',
                'property'  => 'name',
                'required'  => false,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');},
                'empty_value' => 'No category'));

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a constructor that takes an array as an argument for the `SwitchPortfolioType` class:

```
public function __construct($myArray)
{
    $this->myArray = $myArray;
}
```

And, in your controller, pass it your dynamic array when you create the form object:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new SwitchPortfolioType($myArray), $entity);
```

Now you can use the array inside the form type with `$this->myArray`.

Answer (score 0):

See in this document page, You can set dynamic data by using `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` in form builder area.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#how-to-dynamically-generate-forms-based-on-user-data